# Suppress "output truncated before terminating nul"

Tags: c, gcc

I'm building a binary structure that has to include a certain <strike>string</strike> character sequence. To set the character sequence, I'm using

```
struct {
    char preamble[6];
    uint8_t check;
} msg;

strncpy(msg.preamble, "abcdef", 6);
```

This gives me a warning:

```
src\main.cpp:41:9: warning: 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' output truncated before terminating nul copying
6 bytes from a string of the same length [-Wstringop-truncation]
```

I'd like to keep the build log free of warnings, so that I can see actual issues quicker.

How can I fix/suppress this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you have isn't a string, don't treat it as such, i.e. don't use `strncpy`.  Use `memcpy` instead.

```
memcpy(msg.preamble, "abcdef", 6);
```